# How to make image background transparent and can adjust fuzz factor?

Tags: c#, image

I like to make white background transparent. However some whites are not remove. How do I remove the other similar white colors?

My code-

```
string currentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
int width = pictureBox1.Width;
int height = pictureBox1.Height;
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

bm.MakeTransparent(System.Drawing.Color.White);
System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)bm;
img.Save(currentPath + "\\temp\\logo.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Sounds like you want alpha transparency.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Bitmap.GetPixel()` and `Bitmap.SetPixel()` to make non-white colors transparent. For example:

```
for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++) 
    {
        Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
        if ((c.B + c.R + c.G > 660))
            c = Color.FromArgb(0, c.R, c.G, c.B);
        bm.SetPixel(x, y, c);
    }
}
```

This would loop through every pixel in the bitmap and set all the slightly off-white colors' Alpha to 0, which would make that pixel transparent. You could change what the Pixel's R, G, and B values have to add up to and make it higher to make the pixel have to be more white, or make that value lower, which will cause more off-white pixels to be make transparent. Not sure how efficient this code is, but hopefully it will help. You could also use `bitmap.GetBrightness` and instead of `if ((c.B + c.R + c.G > 660))
                c = Color.FromArgb(0, c.R, c.G, c.B);` you could try something like `if (c.GetBrightness() > 240)
                c = Color.FromArgb(0, c.R, c.G, c.B);`

HTH